# Using filter and logical operation

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to write a code but I have not been able to achieve the result. I am using filter from tidyverse. I am new to R so finding this hard.

This is the form of the dataframe:

```
ID  Meeting1    Meeting2
P40 Yes         NA
P40 Yes         NA
P40 NA          Yes
P42 NA          Yes
P43 NA          Yes
P44 Yes         NA
P44 NA          Yes
```

I am trying to write a code that filter Id and find observation that have been to meeting 2 but wans't able to go to meet 1 first before going to meet 2.

This is the code I wrote:

```
tt %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Meeting1 == "Yes" | Meeting2 == "Yes")
```

Comment: If you share the code you tried in your best attempt, we can help you understand why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First we make sure the meeting columns are character, not factor. Then we replace `NA` with a more useful `"No"`, and then we `filter`:

```
dd %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Meeting")), as.character) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Meeting")), ~ifelse(is.na(.), "No", .)) %>% 
  filter(any(Meeting2 == "Yes") & !any(Meeting1 == "Yes"))
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups:   ID [2]
#   ID    Meeting1 Meeting2
#   <fct> <chr>    <chr>   
# 1 P42   No       Yes     
# 2 P43   No       Yes
```

---

Works on this sample data:

```
  dd = read.table(text = 'ID  Meeting1    Meeting2
P40 Yes         NA
P40 Yes         NA
P40 NA          Yes
P42 NA          Yes
P43 NA          Yes
P44 Yes         NA
P44 NA          Yes', header = T)
```

Comment: Factors and NA were problematic. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 filter(any(cumsum(!is.na(Meeting1)) == 0 & cumsum(!is.na(Meeting2)) == 1))

  ID    Meeting1 Meeting2
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>   
1 P42   <NA>     Yes     
2 P43   <NA>     Yes
```